# laravel insert data in multiple table with relationship

Tags: laravel

User will add data in accident, vehicle tables at the sametime

I manage to add data in accident table but not on vehicle my code is.

**User model:**

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable{

     use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

     public function accident(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Accident');
     }
}
```

**Accident model:**

```
class Accident extends Model{

     public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     }
     public function vehicle(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
     }
}
```

**Vehicle model:**

```
class Vehicle extends Model{

     public function accident(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Accident');
     }
 }
```

**My controller and the data:**

```
 public function postAccident(Request $request){

    $accidentLocation = $request['location'];
    $accidentDateTime = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->format('y-m-d g:i:s A');

    $accident = new Accident();
    $accident->accidentLocation = $accidentLocation;
    $accident->accidentDateTime = $accidentDateTime;

    $request->user()->accident()->save($accident);

    $vehicle = new Vehicle(); // <-- Im trying to do this
    $vehicle->vehicleType = "SUV";

    $vehicle()->save();

    return response()->json(['msg' => "Successfully submitted"], 200);  

}
```

**MIGRATION TABLE**

**Accident:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('accidentLocation', 100);
        $table->dateTime('accidentDatetime');
        $table->string('weatherCondition', 30);
        $table->string('accidentCase', 20);
        $table->string('roadCharacter', 20);
        $table->string('roadCondition', 20);
        $table->string('collisionType', 20);
        $table->string('accidentType', 20);
        $table->integer('vehicleNumber');
        $table->string('accidentStatus', 10);
        $table->text('file_attachment');
        $table->string('user_id');
    });
}
```

**Vehicle:**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('accident_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('accident_id')->references('id')->on('accidents');
        $table->string('vehicleType', 20);
        $table->string('vehicleMake', 20);
        $table->string('vehicleModel', 20);
        $table->string('vehiclePlateNumber', 10);
        $table->string('vehicleClassification', 15);
        $table->string('vehicleOwner', 50);
        $table->string('vehicleRegistration', 30);

        $table->integer('driver_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('driver_id')->references('id')->on('drivers');
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the error? instead of `$vehicle()->save();` TRY `$accident->vehicle()->attach($vehicle->id)`

Comment: badmethod attach error

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eloquent` relationship to save the data

```
public function postAccident(Request $request){

    $accidentLocation = $request['location'];
    $accidentDateTime = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->format('y-m-d g:i:s A');

    $accident = new Accident();
    $accident->accidentLocation = $accidentLocation;
    $accident->accidentDateTime = $accidentDateTime;

    $request->user()->accident()->save($accident);

    $vehicle = new Vehicle(); // <-- Im trying to do this
    $vehicle->vehicleType = "SUV";

    // Save the vehicle associates accident
    $accident->vehicle()->save($vehicle);



    return response()->json(['msg' => "Successfully submitted"], 200);  

}
```

Another thing you have to do,

Remove this on your migration if you don't have `Driver` model yet and not saving any

```
$table->integer('driver_id')->unsigned(); 
$table->foreign('driver_id')->references('id')->on('drivers');
```

Comment: I tried this one before but the error is SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pards`.`vehicles`, CONSTRAINT `vehicles_driver_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`driver_id`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `vehicles` (`vehicleType`, `accident_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (SUV, 18, 2016-05-26 04:26:45, 2016-05-26 04:26:45))

Comment: @MajikeroGallardo Can you include your migration file for this?

Comment: Migration file posted

Comment: Remove the driver id foreign key for now

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but this code includes 2 calls to `save`. Eloquent, the ORM, should determine and execute that. That is the component responsible for syncing the objects in memory with their stored counterparts.

Answer (score -1):

$accident->vehicle()->save($vehicle); is correct .

and I removed the $table->integer('driver_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('driver_id')->references('id')->on('drivers'); and it work

Comment: This is a copy from mine